# BusyBox help to write file

Tags: file, replace, url-rewriting, busybox

I need to create a file from a template where I must replace two words in this file with two words from another file.

FILE 1 (config.ovpn) TEMPLETE

```
dev tun
proto tcp
cipher AES-128-CBC
auth SHA1

<connection>
nobind
remote localhost 1194
http-proxy IP1 8080 auto
connect-retry-max 2
</connection>

<connection>
nobind
remote localhost 1194
http-proxy IP2 8080 auto
connect-retry-max 2
</connection>

resolv-retry 3
persist-key
persist-tun
client
verb 3
auth-user-pass
```

FILE 2 (IP.txt)

```
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
```

I want to replace IP1 (config.ovpn) with 1.1.1.1 (Ip.txt)
same for IP2

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION

```
cat config.ovpn | sed "s/IP1/$(sed -n '1p' IP.txt)/" | sed "s/IP2/$(sed -n '2p' IP.txt)/" > config_ok.ovpn
```